# Calculating Cohen's Kappa for a dataset when categories differ between examples

Tags: agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

Cohen's Kappa is a measure of inter-annotator agreement that is traditionally applied to a setting where you have two raters who each classify $N$ items into $C$ mutually exclusive categories. For example, in a 4-class classification dataset with 1000 examples, $N = 1000$ and $|C| = 4$.

In some settings, $|C|$ differs across the items. For example, suppose you have a dataset where each example is a (question, paragraph) pair, and the annotators are asked to select a substring of the paragraph that answers the question. In this case, the $C$ for each example is the set of all possible substrings in the paragraph (and the paragraph differs in each example).

Does it make sense to calculate Cohen's Kappa in this setting? While it is possible to calculate the Cohen's kappa on a per-example basis, is there a reasonable way of computing an aggregated Cohen's kappa across the whole dataset (the $N = 1000$ examples)? One could imagine taking a simple average, or doing a weighted average based on the prior probability of chance agreement, etc.

If you have any pointers to techniques or past literature, that'd be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time calculating kappa here, because there are so many things you could choose. If annotator one says the substring is "he went to bed", 2 says "it was late and he went to bed" and 3 days "he went to bed as quickly as he could" do they agree or not?

Comment: Ah, that was just a hypothetical setting, but I am mostly interested in the setting where the annotators select the exact same category $c \in |C|$ (i.e., they select exactly the same substring). Beyond defining a notion of what observed agreement looks like, it's very unclear to me what's the right way to aggregate across individual examples.